# How to use Angular Library directly from Github to another Angular Project without publishing the Angular Library to NPM

Tags: angular

TL;DR - I'm looking for a solution that doesn't require publishing to NPM or using NPM symlink

I've created two demo repos in Github, one is for the Angular Library and one for an Angular application that will use the Angular Library. I'm not allowed to publish the Angular Library to NPM due to privacy and security reasons. So I would like to npm install the Angular Library directly into the Angular application.

I've created the Angulary Library using `ng new my-lib --no-create-application` and `ng generate library my-lib`, and the Angular application with just `ng new my-app`. I'm not sure how I'm going to install `my-lib` into `my-app`.

I tried to `ng build` and `npm pack` the dist of `my-lib` then push everything in Github. But when I installed `my-lib` in `my-app` by putting `"my-lib": "git@github.com:<github_user>/my-lib.git"` in package.json and doing `npm install` it says that cannot find module when I try to import in my app.module.ts.

Comment: https://georghoeller.dev/nx-dev/

Comment: @Vikas I can't use monorepos, my manager will kill me

Comment: I'm not sure i understood quite right wat you want to do, but maybe this will make sense; create a projects folder at the root of your app, libraries should go there. Then you can add them in your angular.json of your main app, and when you build you app it build the libraries also. If you do this however the lib will be on the same repos of the main app. If you don't want to i suggest using git sub repo.

Comment: Actually what I want is pretty simple. I have to repo, one Angular app and the other is Angular component library. I just want to `npm install` the Angular component library into Angular app. No publishing, no local npm symlinks, no monorepos, no github sub repo. I just want to know the exact steps, like do I need to build and how would I do npm install the library.

Comment: @CRIS have you found a way for this?